# Count the number of integer solutions of a linear equation

Tags: combinatorics

What kind of approach can be used to solve this specific problem? An easy one if possible.

I thought about the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle; I think using generating functions will be more difficult.

> Given that the variables $x_i$ are natural numbers.
>
> Find how many solutions exist for the equation:
>
> $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 24$$
>
> when given
>
> $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 > x_4 + x_5 + x_6$$

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  Are you assuming the $x_i$ are in some particular order?  Non-ascending, maybe, or non-descending?   Have you looked at the same problem for, smaller numbers than 24?

Comment: Also, are they positive integers or nonnegative integers?

Comment: True.  I assumed they were nonnegative integers but I frequently assume things incorrectly.

Comment: I edited. non-negative

Answer (score 13):

Outline: Let $A$ be the number of solutions (in non-negative integers) with $x_1+x_2+x_3\gt x_4+x_5+x_6$. Let $B$ be the number of solutions with $x_1+x_2+x_3\lt x_4+x_5+x_6$. And let $T$ be the  number of solutions with equality.

By symmetry $A=B$. We know the total number $N$ of solutions with no restriction. So $2A+T=N$ and therefore $A=\frac{N-T}{2}$.

Now we only need $T$. This is $W^2$, where $W$ is the number of solutions of $y_1+y_2+y_3=12$.

Comment: wow, thanks.
the speed you answered it .
I thought its a very hard question.
maybe my foundations not that strong

Comment: You are welcome. Symmetry is our friend.

Comment: (Should C be T?)

Comment: Yes, thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that they are nonnegative integers:

The number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = k$ is $\dbinom{k+2}{2}$ by the [Stars and Bars approach.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Therefore, we can add up the number of ways for every combination of $k$ that works - if the first three add to $k$, the second three add to $24-k$. In addition, we let $k$ go from $13$ to $24$, so that the inequality holds.

Thus, the answer is 
$$
\sum_{k=13}^{24} \dbinom{k+2}{2} \cdot \dbinom{26 - k}{2}
$$

EDIT: The other answer is much better! But I'll leave this here.

Comment: I do not agree that the other answer (mine) is better. They are different. Your procedure can be easily generalized, with sum of the first $k$ less than the sum of the last $l$.. Mine only deals with sum of first $k$ greater than the sum of the last $k$.

Comment: Haha, I come from a math contest background, so I always try to find ways to make the calculations as simple as possible. With problems like this, it's always best to exploit any symmetries.

Comment: I also have a contest background, but for the last many years on the other side of the game, making up problems, marking.

Comment: Ooh, that's awesome. What contests do you write for?

Comment: I should avoid specifics. Never IMO, but a national contest, an international one, and a regional much lower level one.